# Xamarin Forms: Not able to get the list view populate with the custom control

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm not able to attach a list dynamically using a custom control in Xamarin forms. Please let me know what am I missing here.

I'm able to create slots for string attribute, but not any object.

Custom Control Content View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="MMSG.Mobile.CustomControls.DashboardItem">
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>

    <Label x:Name="displayText"></Label>

        <ListView x:Name="demoList">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </StackLayout>


</ContentView.Content>
```

Custom Control Code behind:

```
public partial class DashboardItem : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DisplayNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DisplayName), typeof(string), typeof(DashboardItem), default(string));
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayName)); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ListDisplayNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ListDisplayName), typeof(List<Demo>), typeof(DashboardItem));
    public List<Demo> ListDisplayName
    {
        get { return (List<Demo>)GetValue(ListDisplayNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListDisplayNameProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListDisplayName)); }
    }

    public DashboardItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displayText.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(DisplayName), source: this));
        demoList.SetBinding(ItemsView<Cell>.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding(nameof(ListDisplayName), source: this));
    }
}
```

XAML Page, where I'm using the custom control:

```
<customControl:DashboardItem DisplayName="{Binding DashboardItm.Tile.Title}" ListDisplayName="{Binding Demos.Demos}">
```

ViewModel:

```
public class DashboardSummaryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public DashboardItm DashboardItm { get; set; }

    public DemoList Demos { get; set; }

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        //GetWalletSummary();
        DashboardItm = new DashboardItm();
        DashboardItm.Tile = new DashboardTile(){Title = "Sample Text"};

        Demos = new DemoList();
        Demos.Demos = new List<Demo>() { new Demo() { Name = "a" }, new Demo() { Name = "b" } };
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the DisplayName property value being displayed on the UI. But I'm not able to get the ListView populated using a customControl.

Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: `ListDisplayName` is a property of type `string`. Its bindable property is expecting a `List<string>`. You are binding a property of type `List<Demo>`. None of these match!

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your reply. It helped me track my mistake